# Intellij Scala formatting removes space on multiline line comments

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Intellij (2019.3) formats the following Scala code as expected

```scala
//comment 1
val int =
  1
```

But adding another comment on newline removes the space before `1`

```scala
//comment 1
//comment 2
val int =  
1
```

How do make sure the space before `1` is maintained?

Answer (score 0):

Please go into file -> settings and search for code style select scala

make sure indent is 1 this will solve your issue.

[image]

Comment: The indent shift all lines in the file to left. I'm trying to maintain the spaces.